# Why would keyboard skip certain links while tabbing in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, accessibility

I am trying to look at the accessibility of a site and I've noticed that some of the links are not ever being highlighted when tabbing through them in Chrome.. (the text/images in the white nav bar). I've tried adding tab-index to them but that seems to have no effect. Why would they be ignored by the tab key? It works in Firefox.

Is there any reasonable reason for this, or is it likely a bug in Chrome

http://www.vawsec.on.ca/womens-place-elgins-emergency-shelter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, Chromium doesn’t tab to these links.

In Firefox it works, though. But there is no styling change if one of these links is focused. You can add CSS for it with the pseudo-class `:focus`. Often it makes sense to add this selector to the rule which you already have for `:hover`, so that hover and focus share the same styles.

<s>Maybe (just a wild guess, didn’t test) Chromium focuses these links when a CSS change is applied on focus?</s>

It seems to be an issue with `float`. I made a minimal example of the links which are not focusable:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

<head>
<title>Focus problem in Chromium</title>
<!-- see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18768563/1591669 -->

<style>
#icon_bar_sub_pages ul li img {float:left;}
#icon_bar_sub_pages ul li span {float:left;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="icon_bar_sub_pages"> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/24-hour-helpline"><img src="" alt="Phone" width="52" height="56"/><span>1</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/womens-place-elgins-emergency-shelter"><img src="" alt="House" width="53" height="48" /><span>2</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/community-based-counselling"><img src="" alt="Chairs" width="79" height="44"/><span>3</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/prevention-together"><img src="" alt="Apple" width="46" height="49" /><span>4</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/help-for-children"><img src="" alt="Backpacks" width="69" height="49"/><span>5</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you remove/change the float of the `img` and/or the `span`, the links can be focused again:

```
#icon_bar_sub_pages ul li img {float:left;}
#icon_bar_sub_pages ul li span {float:left;}
```

Comment: yup I've styled the focus already but it's not on live yet.  The links on the homepage which are very similar *do* get focus in chromium

Comment: Oh awesome. Doesn't seem to make sense why they'd skip floating things, but good to know what the issue was!